# How To Display A base64 Encoded Image Into A UIImageView In Xcode 6?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, base64

I wanna create an application that gets base64 image data and shows it in a UIImageView. I've read a lot about how to implement this but there were no success. I know that I have a valid base64 image data, but I can't display it in a UIImageView.

This is My Code:

```
[ImageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:ImageData]]]];
```

`ImageView` is my UIImageView And `ImageData` is my base64 data as a NSString.

Answer (score 0):

@Hossein MK..
Use Below Code

```
[ImageView setImage:[decodeBase64ToImage:ImageData]]]];
```

//Call These Method to Convert from BASE64 to Image

```
  - (UIImage *)decodeBase64ToImage:(NSString *)strEncodeData {
          NSData *data = [[NSData alloc]initWithBase64EncodedString:strEncodeData options:NSDataBase64DecodingIgnoreUnknownCharacters];
          return [UIImage imageWithData:data];
        }
```

Happy Coding..

## Edited Answer Below, Try this one.

**Encoding :**

```
- (NSString *)encodeToBase64String:(UIImage *)image {
 return [UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength];
}
```

**Decoding :**

```
- (UIImage *)decodeBase64ToImage:(NSString *)strEncodeData {
  NSData *data = [[NSData alloc]initWithBase64EncodedString:strEncodeData options:NSDataBase64DecodingIgnoreUnknownCharacters];
  return [UIImage imageWithData:data];
}
```

//Code

```
NSData* data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image_B64_encoded, 1.0f);
NSString *strEncoded = [Base64 encode:data];
NSData* data = [Base64 decode:strEncoded];
NewImageimage.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

//this way , you can easily set in `UIImageView`

Comment: it is not working. i use this code but when i set the image of UIImageView it gives me a blank UIImageView. :-(

Answer (score 0):

I have found my answer. my own code was correct. the problem was a new line character that was added in the base64 code. this is my new code:

```
[ImageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[ImageData stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""]]]]];
```

I had a valid base64 code but because I was sending it through a web socket, web socket send 1024 characters each time, and there was an unwanted newline character after 1024 characters.

Comment: According to your own answer, you do not have a base64 encoded image at all. Your problem was with how you obtained the URL of the image data. That's a big difference.